# Week End Logic is giving 53 weeks

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, week-number

I am trying to create week End for all weeks
my logic is

```
dateadd(day, 7-datepart(Weekday, basicstart), basicstart)
```

It is generating Week End As '`4-Jan-2014`' for last week of `2013` means `29-Dec-2013` to `31-Dec-2013`
but it is not merging data for `1-Jan-2014` to `4-Jan-2014` in same week Instead it is generating another Week with same name (`4-Jan-2014`)

This means my data is getting 2 separate weeks of 4 Jan and 4 Jan

Can any one help?

Comment: Yes I know there is always more then 52 week in a year.
All I want to do is add those excess days of 53 week.(29,30 & 31 Dec)
In 1st week of jan 2014 as it is not complete week And my week is ending on Sat which is 4 Jan 2014

Answer (score 1):

Part of that week is in 2013, part of that week is in 2014.

The first and last week of the year are subject to the following, peculiarities.

a) There are always 53 weeks in a year

b) A week can have between 1 and 7 days. 7 is the most common

**Merging weeks**

You could do something like

```
CASE WHEN myweek = 53 THEN 1 ELSE myweek END AS myweek
```

Merging 1 and 53 won't help, because then you have the situation of

a) There are always 52 weeks per year

b) A week can have between 7 and 9 days

c) Most of week could be in one year, but you are placing it the opposite year

Comment: How about "There are either 52 or 53 weeks in a year. A week always has exactly 7 days."? That's the standard ([ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates)), according to Wikipedia anyway, also the norm here (in NL), and it seems like the OP is looking for either that, or something very close to that, based on the question.

Comment: All you have to is figure out how to make 365 / 7 and 366 / 7 be calcated without a decimal or rounding and you can have it.

Comment: No, that is not necessary. The first and last week of a year may include days of another year.

Comment: So for any given week, it can be in one of two years?

Comment: I'm not sure if this answers your question as "yes" or as "no", but 30 December 2013 to 5 January 2014 is one week, and that one week has one week number: it's week 1 of 2014. Even though it also contains two days from 2013. But, re-reading the question, I now no longer think this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Yes I know there is always more then 52 week in a year. All I want to do is add those excess days of 53 week.(29,30 & 31 Dec) In 1st week of jan 2014 as it is not complete week And my week is ending on Sat which is 4 Jan 2014

Answer (score 1):

52 * 7 = 364.  Years with 365 days will always span 53 weeks.  Years with 366 days will usually span 53 weeks and sometimes span 54 weeks. A calendar year of 365 or 366 days will always share at least one week with an adjacent calendar year.

The SQL-style solution to this problem is to make and maintain a calendar table where you can store all of your business calendar rules.

Comment: Yes I know there is always more then 52 week in a year. All I want to do is add those excess days of 53 week.(29,30 & 31 Dec) In 1st week of jan 2014 as it is not complete week And my week is ending on Sat which is 4 Jan 2014

Comment: Edit your question to add your schema and the query.  Your question is currently too vague.

Comment: I want it to return week53 for 30-dec-2019, but it gives week1. How to do that?